# PL/SQL Join Collection Object problems

Tags: object, collections, plsql, oracle11g

I am working with an Oracle 11g database, release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64 bit production

I have written the following procedure which uses a cursor to collect batches of benefit_ids (which are simply of type NUMBER) from a table called benefit_info.  For each benefit_id within each batch, I need to obtain the associated customers and then perform various calculations etc.  So far I have the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ben_correct(in_bulk_collect_limit IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1000)
IS

   TYPE ben_identity_rec IS RECORD
      (
          life_scd_id   NUMBER,
          benefit_id    NUMBER
      );

   TYPE ben_identity_col IS TABLE OF ben_identity_rec INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   life_col ben_identity_col;

   ben_id NUMBER;

   CURSOR benefit_cur
   IS
     SELECT benefit_id FROM benefit_info;

    TYPE benefit_ids_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    benefit_ids benefit_ids_t;

    PROCEDURE get_next_set_of_incoming(out_benefit_ids OUT NOCOPY benefit_ids_t)
    IS
    BEGIN
       FETCH benefit_cur
           BULK COLLECT INTO out_benefit_ids
           LIMIT in_bulk_collect_limit;
    END;

BEGIN
   OPEN benefit_cur;

   LOOP
      get_next_set_of_incoming(benefit_ids);

      /*
       The code below is too slow as each benefit_id is considered
       individually. Want to change FOR LOOP into LEFT JOIN of benefit_ids
       */
      FOR indx IN 1 .. benefit_ids.count LOOP

          ben_id := benefit_ids(indx);

          SELECT c.life_scd_id, c.benefit_id
          BULK COLLECT INTO life_col
          FROM customer c
          WHERE c.benefit_id = ben_id;

          -- Now do further processing with life_col
      END LOOP;

      EXIT WHEN benefit_ids.count = 0;

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE benefit_cur;

END;
/
```

As indicated in the code above, the FOR indx IN 1 .. LOOP is VERY slow, particularly as there are millions of benefit_ids.  However, I am aware I can replace the entire FOR LOOP with something like:

```
SELECT c.life_scd_id, c.benefit_id
BULK COLLECT INTO life_col
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN table(benefit_ids) b
WHERE b.benefit_id IS NOT NULL;
```

However, for that to work I think I need to declare an Object type at the schema level as I think in the SELECT query you can join on pure tables or collections of objects.  Therefore, from the procedure I remove

```
TYPE benefit_ids_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

and instead at the schema level I have defined

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ben_id FORCE AS object
    (
      benefit_id number
    );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE benefit_ids_t FORCE AS TABLE OF ben_id;
```

My revised code essentially becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ben_correct(in_bulk_collect_limit IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1000)
IS

   sql_str VARCHAR2(1000);

   TYPE ben_identity_rec IS RECORD
      (
          life_scd_id   NUMBER,
          benefit_id    NUMBER
      );

   TYPE ben_identity_col IS TABLE OF ben_identity_rec INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   life_col ben_identity_col;

   CURSOR benefit_cur
   IS
     SELECT benefit_id FROM benefit_info;

    --- benefit_ids_t has now been declared at schema level
    benefit_ids benefit_ids_t;

    PROCEDURE get_next_set_of_incoming(out_benefit_ids OUT NOCOPY benefit_ids_t)
    IS
    BEGIN
       FETCH benefit_cur
           BULK COLLECT INTO out_benefit_ids
           LIMIT in_bulk_collect_limit;
    END;

BEGIN
   OPEN benefit_cur;

   LOOP
      get_next_set_of_incoming(benefit_ids);

      sql_str := 'SELECT c.life_scd_id, c.benefit_id
          FROM customer c
          LEFT JOIN table(benefit_ids) b
          WHERE b.benefit_id IS NOT NULL';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_str BULK COLLECT INTO life_col;

      -- Now do further processing with life_col

      EXIT WHEN benefit_ids.count = 0;

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE benefit_cur;

END;
/
```

However, this generates ORA-24344 and PLS-00386 errors, ie type mismatch found at 'OUT_BENEFIT_IDS' between FETCH cursor and INTO variables.

I sort of understand that it is complaining that benefit_ids_t is now a table of ben_ids, which are in turn objects of type number, which is in't quite the same as a table of numbers.

I've tried various attempts at resolving the issues, but I can't seem to quite get it right.  Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Also, any general comments to improve are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your table type to be of an object containing a number field, it can just be a table of numbers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE benefit_ids_t FORCE AS TABLE OF number;
```

Or you can use a built-in type like `sys.odcinumberlist`, but having your own type under your control isn't a bad thing.

You don't want to use dynamic SQL though; this:

```
  sql_str := 'SELECT c.life_scd_id, c.benefit_id
      FROM customer c
      LEFT JOIN table(benefit_ids) b
      WHERE b.benefit_id IS NOT NULL';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_str BULK COLLECT INTO life_col;
```

won't work because `benefit_ids` isn't in scope when that dynamic statement is executed. You can just do it statically:

```
SELECT c.life_scd_id, c.benefit_id
BULK COLLECT INTO life_col
FROM table(benefit_ids) b
JOIN customer c
ON c.benefit_id = b.column_value;
```

which is closer to what you had in your original code.

Your `EXIT` is also in the wrong place - it will try to process rows in a loop when it doesn't find any. I wouldn't bother with the separate fetch procedure at all, it's easier to follow with the fetch directly in the loop:

```
BEGIN
   OPEN benefit_cur;

   LOOP
      FETCH benefit_cur
         BULK COLLECT INTO benefit_ids
         LIMIT in_bulk_collect_limit;

      EXIT WHEN benefit_ids.count = 0;

      SELECT c.life_scd_id, c.benefit_id
      BULK COLLECT INTO life_col
      FROM table(benefit_ids) b
      JOIN customer c
      ON c.benefit_id = b.column_value;

      -- Now do further processing with life_col

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE benefit_cur;
END;
```

---

If you did really want your object type, you *could* keep that, but you would need to make your cursor return instances of that object, via its default constructor:

```
CURSOR benefit_cur
IS
  SELECT ben_id(benefit_id) FROM benefit_info;
```

The customer query join would then be:

```
SELECT c.life_scd_id, c.benefit_id
BULK COLLECT INTO life_col
FROM table(benefit_ids) b
JOIN customer c
ON c.benefit_id = b.benefit_id;
```

As it's an object type you can refer to it's field name, `benefit_id`, rather than the generic `column_value` from the scalar type table.

Comment: Lovely,  I didn't realise that the table type could simply be declared as a table of numbers rather than a table of objects which then happen to be numbers.   I  then wouldn't have known about using b.column_value.  Finally, thanks for pointing out that the EXIT was in the wrong place - I should have spotted that at least

Comment: Just  one question.  Does it matter that you've done FROM tables(benefit_ids) b and then performed the JOIN?  Can it be the other way round, namely FROM customers with the JOIN on table(benefit_ids)?

Comment: @user2948208 - no, it doesn't matter for inner joins really, the optimiser will pick the best order (though it doesn't know the cardinality of the table collection expression); but logically aren't you only looking for customers which have IDs from the collection? You had a left join i your second block but I'm not sure why - do you really want customer which *don't* have an benefit_id in the collection? That would make the collection pointless...

Comment: Yes, agreed.  And lastly, the only reason for the procedure for the FETCH was simply due to the code being originally inspired and/or provided by Steven Feuerstein.   Like you I wouldn't have separated this into a separate procedure for one FETCH routine, but I guess now that benefit_ids_t has been redefined more generally to be a table of numbers (rather than previous of objects called benefit_ids), I guess the FETCH procedure could be called by several cursors.  I presume that is possible now

Comment: The procedure specifies the fetch is from the `benefit_cur` cursor, so no, it isn't reusable for multiple cursors. If you were using the same cursor in multiple places then maybe it would make some sense to refactor it like that, but not sure it really adds much. But that's down to taste/standards/etc., functionally it doesn't matter.